# Why does sshd ask for a host service principal when authenticating a user via pam or KerberosAuthentication

Tags: ssh, kerberos

I've setup Ubuntu for testing purposes. 
-Installed MIT kerberos (latest)
-Installed OpeenSsh(latest)

I've setup and have working both KerberosAuthentication  and pam_krb5 types of authentication as well as GSSAPIAuthentication. All is well there.

When I setup only to use "KerberosAuthentication" or "pam_krb5"  I see requests for host/:

```
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): AS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: NEEDED_PREAUTH: user@HELLO.COM for krbtgt/HELLO.COM@HELLO.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): AS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: NEEDED_PREAUTH: user@HELLO.COM for krbtgt/HELLO.COM@HELLO.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): AS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: ISSUE: authtime 1511154551, etypes {rep=17 tkt=18 ses=17}, user@HELLO.COM for krbtgt/HELLO.COM@HELLO.COM
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): AS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: ISSUE: authtime 1511154551, etypes {rep=17 tkt=18 ses=17}, user@HELLO.COM for krbtgt/HELLO.COM@HELLO.COM
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): TGS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: ISSUE: authtime 1511154551, etypes {rep=17 tkt=18 ses=17}, user@HELLO.COM for host/sshserver@HELLO.COM
Nov 20 00:09:11 kdcname krb5kdc[12476](info): TGS_REQ (2 etypes {16 17}) 192.168.1.104: ISSUE: authtime 1511154551, etypes {rep=17 tkt=18 ses=17}, user@HELLO.COM for host/sshserver@HELLO.COM
```

Is the host/ service principal needed for something (TGS_REQ)?

In my mind all you need is AS_REQ to validate the user's password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to prevent man in the middle attacks against the KDC.

I found the answer in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=dGMd-uay-lkC&pg=PT124&dq=Man-in-the-Middle%20Attacks%20kerberos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8PXC8M7XAhXQRN8KHerbCO8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Man-in-the-Middle%20Attacks%20kerberos&f=false):

Pg 108/109 of kerberos the definitive guide seems authoritative.

I will delay in accepting this as an answer. There should be more of a write up here and my intent was not to self promote and copy/pasting more than a sentence or so seems inappropriate.